# How to get ANY in GROUP BY query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table of test results and a table of treatment dates. I want to assemble a dataset with the test results and an indicator equal to 1 if the patient was on treatment at the time of the test.

The testresult table has PatientID, Date, and Value columns. The treatmentDate table has PatientID, along with the Start date and End date of each treatment. A PatientID may have have started and stopped treatment many times, and could have any number of tests both on and off treatment.

Here's the query I came up with:

```
select a.PatientID
,a.[Date]
,a.[Value]
,SUM(CASE WHEN a.[Date]>b.[Start] and a.[Date]<=b.[End] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as IsOnTreatment
from testresults a
left join
treatmentDates b on a.PatientID=b.PatientID
group by a.PatientID,a.[Date],a.[Value]
```

In this case, `SUM` works because treatments never overlap. But in other situations where I might want to do this kind of thing, that might not be true. `ANY` has a different purpose in SQL Server, but is there a different window function to tell me if *any* row has a match, rather than `SUM` of all the matches?

Only thing I can think of is to wrap that line in another `CASE` statement:

```
select a.PatientID
,a.[Date]
,a.[Value]
,CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN a.[Date]>b.[Start] and a.[Date]<=b.[End] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as IsOnTreatment
from testresults a
left join
treatmentDates b on a.PatientID=b.PatientID
group by a.PatientID,a.[Date],a.[Value]
```

Comment: How about change SUM() to MAX() ?

Comment: Instead of group by you can use your case statement in where condition like --->>  where 1 = ( CASE WHEN a.[Date]>b.[Start] and a.[Date]<=b.[End] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't take any data from treatments, a simple `exists` should suffice:

```
select a.PatientID, a.[Date], a.[Value],
  case when exists (
    select 0 from treatmentDates b
    where a.PatientID=b.PatientID and a.[Date]>b.[Start] and a.[Date]<=b.[End]
  ) then 1 else 0 end as [IsOnTreatment]
from testresults a;
```

If you need some columns from the treatments table, you can move the subquery into an `outer apply` and add `top (1)` to it.